# Why update fails because of unique index while there isn't duplicate value?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I guess this image explains everything:

[image]

See? I'm setting the value of `2`, but it says `0` is duplicate. Why? Where that `0` comes from?

---

Here is the table structure:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Mar 04, 2018 at 04:18 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.1.8
SET
   SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET
   AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET
   time_zone = " + 00:00";
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */
;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */
;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */
;
--
-- Database: `spy`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `support_us`
--
CREATE TABLE `support_us` ( `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'null means have not logged in', `full_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER 
SET
   utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `publish_name` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1 means show the name and 0 means don''t', `user_amount` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `final_amount` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, `cell_phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `trans_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'null means it''s just a intention (trans_id hasn''t issued yet by pay.ir)', `status_started` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1 means the user is getting redirect to bank page and 0 means it couldn''t connect to bank port', `send_error_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'go to function.php fine, send() function', `status_finished` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1 means finished successfully and 0 means failed', `verify_error_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'go to function.php fine, verify() function', `card_number` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, `message` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `date_time` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--
--
-- Indexes for table `support_us`
--
ALTER TABLE `support_us` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `trans_id` (`trans_id`), ADD KEY `publish_name` (`publish_name`);
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `support_us`
--
ALTER TABLE `support_us` MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT = 41;
COMMIT;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */
;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */
;
```

Comment: MCVE required. You should be here long enough to know that...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What's MCVE? I use mysql and always such queries works as well. I don't know why today it doesn't work.

Comment: See the documentation of Stackoverflow. This term is mentioned in the requirements to make a question like yours on topic. In short, your question lacks information.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear.  The image *does* convey the issue and the OP repeats it in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the image *does* explain everything.  This is surprising -- usually images are not so informative.

I can think of three possibilities but there might be others.

1. You have a trigger on the table that sets `trans_id` to some other value in this or another table.
2. You have a character in the string that you don't see before the `2`.  The string is converted to a number and a non-numeric character is transformed to a 0.
3. Your syntax is totally off (once I expand the image so I can read the SQL better).

(Note that MySQL puts the value in single quotes even when the column is a number, so the error message provides no evidence of the underlying type.)

In any case, you should not be using single quotes for *number* constants.  And you need a comma instead of `and`.  So, write the query as:

```
update support_us
    set trans_id = 2,
        status_started = 1
    where . . . ;
```

What you have done is set the value of `trans_id` to a boolean expression on *all* the rows that match the `where`.  The value is either 0 or 1 -- so if you have more than two rows, you are guaranteed to get either duplicate trues (1) or duplicate falses (0).

Comment: Actually neither are right. I've added table structure to my question.

Comment: Oh ..! It worked .. But I didn't understand what's the problem. I just broke inline query and wrote it like stairs.

Comment: Oh .. I got the problem .. I have to use `,` instead of `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use `,` instead of `AND` in my query.